# Applying Word Stemming in SearchView for fetch data from Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, searchview, android-searchmanager

I need to fetch list of users from Firebase database using `SeachView` or search dialog and I think word stemming will be best for my app.

Not asking for code but please tell me the alorigthm for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you need to execute a query which should look like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("users");
Query query = usersRef.orderByChild("name").equalTo(newText);
```

So everytime you create a search you should return a new query. So according to this, every time you want to filter on a new condition, you will need to:

1. Create a **new** query based on the new filter:

   ```
   Query query = usersRef.orderByChild("name").equalTo(newText);
   ```
2. Attach a listener to this new created query.
3. Create a new adapter with the results of this new created query, or update the existing one using `notifydatasetchanged()` method.

Comment: So by using equalTo() does firebase gives a list of data or a single item which is equal to newText ?

Comment: Depending on what the query returns. If it finds a single user name, a single user name will be returned otherwise it will return as many as it finds. If the user name is unique, a single user named will be returned.