# Android SearchView Filter ListView from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am quite new to this and have followed a lot of tutorial. The codes are copied mostly from sources. I have a ListView Data from Firebase Realtime Database and I tried to use the SearchView to filter the data. However, when I tried to type anything, my ListView Data was not able to show anything. I am able to view all the data again when the SearchView is empty. There are no errors shown. Is there something I missed out?

MainActivity.java

```
SearchView searchEmail;
ListView listViewUsers;

//a list to store all the user from firebase database
ArrayList<User> users;

//our database reference object
DatabaseReference databaseUsers;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_manage_shoppers);

    //getting the reference of artists node
    databaseUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

    //getting views
    searchEmail = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchEmail);
    listViewUsers = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewUsers);

    //list to store users
    users = new ArrayList<>();

    //creating adapter
    final UserList adapter = new UserList(ManageShoppers.this, users);

    //attaching adapter to the listview
    //listViewUsers.setAdapter(userAdapter);

    //final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ManageShoppers.this, R.layout.layout_user_list, users);
    listViewUsers.setAdapter(adapter);

    databaseUsers.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            //clearing the previous user list
            users.clear();

            //iterating through all the nodes
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                //getting artist
                User user = postSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                //adding artist to the list
                users.add(user);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    searchEmail.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

UserList.java

```
public class UserList extends ArrayAdapter<User> {
    private Activity context;
    List<User> users;

public UserList(Activity context, List<User> users) {
    super(context, R.layout.layout_user_list, users);
    this.context = context;
    this.users = users;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_user_list, null, true);

    TextView textEmail = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textEmail);


    User user = users.get(position);
    textEmail.setText(user.getUserEmail());


    return listViewItem;
}
}
```

User.java

```
public class User {

public String email;
public String password;

public User() {

}

public User(String email, String password) {

    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
}

public String getUserEmail() {
    return email;
}

public String getUserPassword() {
    return password;
}


}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Applying Word Stemming in SearchView for fetch data from Firebase database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50682046/applying-word-stemming-in-searchview-for-fetch-data-from-firebase-database)

Comment: Please check the duplicate to see how you can achieve this.

Comment: I looked at it, but I am not able to understand what I needed to do with the query.

Comment: You need to create a new query for each search.

Comment: I followed exactly from this fyi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45497142/how-to-make-searchview-can-filter-data-from-a-firebase-database

Comment: In your User.java, you have to override toString() method to return email/password/email+password. Hope that helps!