# How to filter FirebaseRecyclerOptions with SearchBar

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I am building a fragment in which i have a searchBar for users and a recyclerView to display them. My question is how to change FirebaseRecyclerView Options every time i type something for searching, I found a solution with another adapter (not FirebaseRecyclerView Adapter) but it uses an ArrayList.

I want something like that for the options.

```
//userList contains all users
private void searchUser(String s) {
    ArrayList<User> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(User object : userList){
        String userName = object.Name + " " + object.Surname;
        if(userName.toLowerCase().contains(s.toLowerCase())){
            list.add(object);
        }
    }
    UserAdapter adapter = new UserAdapter(list);
    myUserList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

How to refresh the options every time i type something on search Bar?

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50682046/applying-word-stemming-in-searchview-for-fetch-data-from-firebase-database/50682657)** out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed a query indeed as @Black Mamba said. I used something like this:

```
Query query;
    if(!(searchTxt.isEmpty())) {
        query = Ref.orderByChild("Surname").startAt(search).endAt(search + "\uf8ff");
    }
    else{
        query = Ref;
    }
```

and the setOnQueryTextListener:

```
if (searchBar != null) {
        searchBar.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                firebaseSearch(newText);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

The firebaseSearch Method retrieves the data from the database.

Answer (score 1):

**if you're familar with firebase recyclerview then firebase recyclerview gives that feature**

firebase.database().ref(`path`).orderByChild().startAt('entered username');

startAt() is keyplayer for this... you have to adjust searchkey on usermodel class so that searchquery of firebase pick specified searcingword from tree of datanode.and later on set in firebase recyclerview

Comment: How to add this on FirebaseRecycler options? Do i set a new Query?

Comment: yes you need to set new query on every filter request for more detail you can watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6h-A3sVIed0&list=PLxefhmF0pcPlqmH_VfWneUjfuqhreUz-O&index=34